# How can I use tree to find a specific file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, directory

I'd like to find a list of files within a complex directory structure that match a specific regex. For example files that have _test_file_ in their file name.

I've tried the following command with little success:

tree -P '*_tree_file_*' .

This returns 0 found files. It seems like there are solutions that use find, but I would like to use tree if possible.

Thanks!

Aki

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to files whose names contain `_test_file_` (in which case, use `find`)? or do you want to find files whose contents contain the characters  `_test_file_` (in which case, use `grep -r`)?

Comment: Have edited above- you're right- using find is the best solution

Answer (score 2):

From the man page:

```
-P pattern
      List  only  those files that match the wild-card pattern.  Note:
      you must use the -a option to also consider those  files  begin‐
      ning  with a dot `.' for matching.  Valid wildcard operators are
      `*' (any zero or more characters), `?' (any  single  character),
      `[...]'  (any single character listed between brackets (optional
      - (dash) for character  range  may  be  used:  ex:  [A-Z]),  and
      `[^...]'  (any  single character not listed in brackets) and `|'
      separates alternate patterns.
```

The output for your command `tree -P '_tree_file_'` would be the files which name exactly match "_tree_file_".

You may try to use wildcard for your request:

```
$ tree -P '*_tree_file_*'
```